# Spring Boot start fails for Autoconfigure on RabbitMQ

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-boot

I have a large Spring boot application with uses amongst other thing RabbitMQ.  I created a `@Configuration` file for the Rabbit queues.  This has been working fine on Spring boot 1.0.2.  Today I upgraded version 1.1.0 and now I am getting an exception on startup.

The problem seems to be that the HealthIndicator picks up that RabbitMQ is available and tries to setup a health indicator for it.  It then promptly fails because it cannot inject the rabbitTemplate.  Part of the error message says, `"Error creating bean with name 'rabbitTemplate': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?"`

The actual exception trace is included below.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'environmentMvcEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.EnvironmentEndpoint]: : Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: java.util.Map org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointAutoConfiguration.healthIndicators; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration$RabbitHealthIndicatorConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private java.util.Map org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration$RabbitHealthIndicatorConfiguration.rabbitTemplates; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.cisco.config.queuing.QueuingConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate com.cisco.config.queuing.QueuingConfiguration.rabbitTemplate; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'rabbitTemplate': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: java.util.Map org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointAutoConfiguration.healthIndicators; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration$RabbitHealthIndicatorConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private java.util.Map org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration$RabbitHealthIndicatorConfiguration.rabbitTemplates; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.cisco.config.queuing.QueuingConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate com.cisco.config.queuing.QueuingConfiguration.rabbitTemplate; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'rabbitTemplate': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:747) ~[spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:462) ~[spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1094) ~[spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:989) ~[spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504) ~[spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475) ~[spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304) ~[spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300) ~[spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:470) ~[spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:459) ~[spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1063) ~[spring-context-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.MvcEndpoints.afterPropertiesSet(MvcEndpoints.java:55) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612) ~[spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549) ~[spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.0.5.RELEASE]
... 92 common frames omitted
```

Comment: can you post your spring configuration xml?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a bug with the new health indicators in Spring Boot. I've raised https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1081.

Until it's fixed you can disable the `HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration` for rabbit by setting `health.rabbit.enabled=false` in your `application.properties`.

Comment: @Larry13767 can you provide a sample project and provide some comments on issue #1081?

Comment: Sure, I am pretty rushed for time on my current project but I should be able to do it for this weekend if that time is ok.